# how to stop viewpager auto slide in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, runnable

I have made an android app in that i have implemented play pause function,But I only knows  about play ,I don't know how to stop sliding on the same button click,I have used two functions for it as below,play is working but pause is not.!
**onClick**

```
    if (!flag) {
        play();
        new Thread(ViewPagerVisibleScroll).start();
        ivPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        flag = true;

    } else {
        pause();
        new Thread(ViewPagerVisibleScroll).start();
        ivPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_btn);
        flag = false;
    }
```

**play and pause**

```
void play() {

        pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        ViewPagerVisibleScroll = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (pos <= adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);

                        viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(6);
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        pos++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    void pause() {

        pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        ViewPagerVisibleScroll = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (pos <= adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);

                        viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(6);
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 300000);
                        pos++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in pause button click :

handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(ViewPagerVisibleScroll);

Try this

Comment: sir it is not working...pls give me some another solution save me pls..!:(